# How to convert one timezone to another (GMT+0530)?

Tags: python, timezone, utc, pytz, gmt

This date format `2018-11-11 01:54:16+00:00` should be converted to `Nov 11, 2018 7:24:16 AM GMT+0530`

```
Input : 2018-11-11 01:54:16+00:00
Expected : Nov 11, 2018 7:24:16 AM GMT+0530
Actual :  Nov 11, 2018 07:24:16 AM IST+0530
```

I'm able to convert the time but not Time-zone as specified above `Expected` & `Actual` (`GMT` & `IST`) . Below snippet details :

```
from pytz import timezone
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime

fmt = "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S %p %Z%z"
dt = '2018-11-11 01:54:16+00:00'
tmp = parser.parse(dt)
t1 = tmp.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata'))
print t1 #prints "2018-11-11 07:24:16+05:30"
print t1.strftime(fmt) #prints "Nov 11, 2018 07:24:16 AM IST+0530"

t1 = tmp.astimezone(timezone('GMT'))
print t1.strftime(fmt)    #prints "Nov 11, 2018 01:54:16 AM GMT+0000"
```

Am I missing something to print `GMT` (instead of `IST`) ?

```
Nov 11, 2018 7:24:16 AM GMT+0530
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a datetime from one arbitrary timezone to another arbitrary timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36362381/how-to-convert-a-datetime-from-one-arbitrary-timezone-to-another-arbitrary-timez)

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Arrow](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/) module would suit this best;

```
>>> import arrow
>>> utc = arrow.utcnow()
>>> utc
<Arrow [2013-05-11T21:23:58.970460+00:00]>

>>> utc = utc.shift(hours=-1)
>>> utc
<Arrow [2013-05-11T20:23:58.970460+00:00]>

>>> local = utc.to('US/Pacific')
>>> local
<Arrow [2013-05-11T13:23:58.970460-07:00]>
```

Specific to your needs this works fine;

```
>>> asia = arrow.now('Asia/Kolkata')
>>> asia.to('GMT').format("MMM D, YYYY HH:mm:ss A ZZ")

'Nov 11, 2018 10:01:24 AM +00:00'
```

Try the [docs](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/); this is very powerful and easy to use module.

Comment: As I posted my code above, i'm getting desired result. But with just a little time difference, Input : 2018-11-11 01:54:16+00:00 , Expected : Nov 11, 2018 7:24:16 AM GMT+0530, Actual : Nov 11, 2018 07:24:16 AM IST+0530 . It's between text IST & GMT.

Comment: ok... just try the arrow library i assure you will be amazed at its ease

Comment: Thanks @Jack. Looking at arrow library. Any luck with above code ? I guess slight correction needed.

Comment: It should be either UTC+0530 or GMT+0530, which is equivalent to IST https://www.timeanddate.com/time/current-number-time-zones.html